# mysql 5.5.24 - weird [Err] 1054 - Unknown column

Tags: mysql

I really don't understand what happens.
I have two tables reponses_vitesse and questions_vitesse, and i try to make an inner join on them.
Oh course my tables have the good fields.
But whatever i try i catch the 1054 error below... And the ID row of course exists in my table...

If i write
SELECT ID, QUESTION.reponses_vitesse, .... etc...
Then i got an [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'QUESTION.reponses_vitesse' in 'field list'

I use mysql 5.5.24

Really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

[SQL]

```
SELECT ID.reponses_vitesse, QUESTION.reponses_vitesse, REPONSE.reponses_vitesse,VALEUR_CONTESTATION.reponses_vitesse, SESSION_ID, 
NOM_QUESTION.questions_vitesse, TEXTE_QUESTION.questions_vitesse, OBLIGATOIRE.questions_vitesse 
FROM reponses_vitesse 
INNER JOIN questions_vitesse ON QUESTION.reponses_vitesse = QUESTION.questions_vitesse`
WHERE SESSION_ID.reponses_vitesse = 'apbt8p7g64g44jdc5o2bpp4t13' 
GROUP BY ID.reponses_vitesse 
ORDER BY ID.reponses_vitesse ASC
```

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'ID.reponses_vitesse' in 'field list'

Comment: I think there is an issue with how you crafted your select query. If you're going to do something like ID.responses_vitesse in your select, there needs to be an aliased table called "ID". For instance, "select ID.response_vitess FROM response_vitesse AS ID". In the future, post your table's schema if you're having these kinds of issues. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

See this line of your query:

```
INNER JOIN questions_vitesse ON QUESTION.reponses_vitesse = QUESTION.questions_vitesse`
```

There are a trailing ` character at the end of it. But no opening.

Answer (score 0):

The specific reason for your error is that you incorrectly format your table/field references.  Instead of "field.table", it should be "table.field".  The error you receive simply happens on the very first field of the select statement because MYSQL can't identify a table called "ID" anywhere in the query.  You first need to reverse all your references.

It should look something like this:

```
SELECT reponses_vitesse.ID, reponses_vitesse.QUESTION,reponses_vitesse.RESPONSE,reponses_vitesse.VALEUR_CONTESTATION, SESSION_ID, questions_vitesse.NOM_QUESTION, questions_vitesse.TEXTE_QUESTION, questions_vitesse.OBLIGATOIRE 
FROM reponses_vitesse 
INNER JOIN questions_vitesse ON reponses_vitesse.QUESTION = questions_vitesse.QUESTION
WHERE reponses_vitesse.SESSION_ID = 'apbt8p7g64g44jdc5o2bpp4t13' 
GROUP BY reponses_vitesse.ID
ORDER BY reponses_vitesse.ID ASC
```